# Wrong keyboard layout when connecting with VNC

Tags: 11.10, vnc

I connect to my ubuntu 11.10 machine from windows trought VNC (ultraVNC or tightVNC), and the keyboard layout is wrong. In both PC I use an spanish keyboard, and works ok, but when I'm using ubuntu trought VNC, some keys are changed, (i.e. - becomes /, etc).

There's a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem here... after some research I've followed reply #22 [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861707&page=3).

(remove vino & vinagre; install vino+vinagre+x11vnc and configure x11vnc)

Now I have the portuguese keys and also can log from vncviewer after the server boot without going first on vmware console to login...